# Script extracting information from .txt to .csv to use in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text, scripting

I'm working with a large amount of files (~4gb worth) which all contain anywhere between 1 and 100 entries with the following format (between two *** is one entry):

```
***
Type:status
Origin: @z_rose yes
Text:  yes
URL: 
ID: 95482459084427264
Time: Mon Jul 25 08:16:06 CDT 2011
RetCount: 0
Favorite: false
MentionedEntities: 20776334 
Hashtags: 
***
***
Type:status
Origin: @aaronesilvers text
Text:  text
URL: 
ID: 95481610861953024
Time: Mon Jul 25 08:12:44 CDT 2011
RetCount: 0
Favorite: false
MentionedEntities: 2226621 
Hashtags: 
***
***
Type:status
Origin: @z_rose text
Text:  text and stuff
URL: 
ID: 95480980026040320
Time: Mon Jul 25 08:10:14 CDT 2011
RetCount: 0
Favorite: false
MentionedEntities: 20776334 
Hashtags: 
***
```

Now I want to somehow import these into Pandas for mass analysis, but obviously I'd have to convert this into a format Pandas can handle. So I want to write a script that converts the above into a .csv looking something like this (User is the file title):

```
User   Type    Origin              Text  URL    ID                Time                          RetCount  Favorite  MentionedEntities  Hashtags
4012987 status  @z_rose yes         yes   Null   95482459084427264  Mon Jul 25 08:16:06 CDT 2011  0           false  20776334            Null
4012987 status  @aaronsilvers text  text Null    95481610861953024   Mon Jul 25 08:12:44 CDT 2011  0           false   2226621            Null
```

`

(Sorry for formatting but you get the idea)
I don't really know where to start though because Im very new to scripting languages, what scripting language would be a good fit for this task? I know about some scripting languages but am not familiar with their limitations and would rather not spend hours learning one only to find out it's not possible. And could you give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does 'User' come from? Is it in the name of the file containing the data for that user?

Comment: I withdraw my question. Missed part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use commas, rather than blanks, as delimiters in your input files to Pandas, particularly since some of the input values have blanks embedded within them. And if you're working with Pandas then for heaven's sake learn at least the rudiments of Python.

```
vars = ['User', 'Type', 'Origin', 'Text', 'URL', 'ID', 'Time', \
    'RetCount', 'Favorite', 'MentionedEntities', 'Hashtags']

user = '12345'
userfileName = '{}.txt'.format(user)

items = {}
for var in vars:
    items[var]=var
print (','.join([items[var] for var in vars]))

first=True
with open(userfileName) as userfile:
    for line in userfile:
        if line.startswith('*'):
            continue
        if line.startswith('Type'):
            if first:
                first=False
            else:
                print (','.join([items[var] for var in vars]))
            items = {}
            for var in vars:
                items[var]=''
            items['User']=user
        p=line.find(':')
        itemName=line[:p]
        itemValue=line[1+p:].strip()
        items[itemName]=itemValue

print (','.join([items[var] for var in vars]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file has regular 12-line blocks, I would suggest the following dictionary-building approach:

```
infile = open(....)

records = []

# Get one 12-line block and split the lines, when possible
block = [infile.readline().strip().split(':', 1) for i in range(12)]

# Repean as needed
while block[0][0]:
    # Convert the non-star lines to a dictionary
    records.append(dict(x for x in block if len(x)==2))
    block = [infile.readline().strip().split(':', 1) for i in range(12)]

data = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(data.columns)
# Index(['Favorite', 'Hashtags', 'ID', 'MentionedEntities', 
#        'Origin', 'RetCount','Text', 'Time', 'Type', 'URL'],
# dtype='object')
```